# Check if String in List of Tuples, THEN access it to print it

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to print the html tag id if it has an id. I want it to print the class if the tag has no id but a class. I want it to print the tag name (img, h1 etc) if there is no id or class. It needs to have only one print, like either id or class or tag but not all. It needs to always favour first id, then class, then tag name, but only display one of them. It is for outputting a sass (like css) template.

I need to see if 'id' is in this list of tuples (which it is):

```
[('class', 'title'), ('id', 'donkey'), ('src', 'images/DonkeyKongLogo.png')]
```

The list is called attrs. Here is my code to see if 'id' is in attrs:

It checks the first tuple and see's 'class' and 'title' but no 'id' which is in the next tuple, so it goes to the next if statement (never finding 'id'). Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
 def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if attrs != []:
        for attr in attrs:
            if ('id' in attr):
                id = attr.index('id')
                self.the_file.writelines(self.indent * self.getpos()[1] + '#' + attr[id+1] + ' {' +'\n')
                self.pos = self.getpos()[1]
                break
            elif ('class' in attr):
                clas = attr.index('class')
                self.the_file.writelines(self.indent * self.getpos()[1] + "." + attr[clas+1] + " {"+'\n')
                self.pos = self.getpos()[1]
                break
            else:
                self.the_file.writelines(self.indent * self.getpos()[1] + tag + " {"+'\n')
                self.pos = self.getpos()[1]
                break
```

Comment: If those `break` statements need to remain then you are always **only** processing the very first value. In that case you can simply do: `if attrs:`, `attr = attrs[0]` and do away with the `for` loop. That doesn't sound right however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> attrs = [('class', 'title'), ('id', 'donkey'), ('src', 'images/DonkeyKongLogo.png')]
>>> 'id' in [item for sub in attrs for item in sub]
True
>>>
```

To print the subsequent value of `'id'` (`'donkey'`), do the following:

```
>>> attrs = [('class', 'title'), ('id', 'donkey'), ('src', 'images/DonkeyKongLogo.png')]
>>> [item[1] for item in attrs if item[0] == 'id'][0]
'donkey'
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I then access the value of id (donkey) to print it out?

Answer (score 1):

Your list of tuples always consist of name-value pairs; just use a `for` loop with tuple unpacking:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    for name, value in attrs:
        if name == 'id':
            value = '#' + value
        elif name == 'class':
            value = '.' + value
        elif:
            value = tag

        self.the_file.writelines(self.indent * self.getpos()[1] + value + ' {\n')
        self.pos = self.getpos()[1]
```

This processes *every* tuple in `attrs`, not just the first (which is what using a `break` keyword will mean). If your really want to only process the first, then use:

```
if attrs:
    name, value = attrs[0]
    if name == 'id':
        value = '#' + value
    elif name == 'class':
        value = '.' + value
    elif:
        value = tag
    self.the_file.writelines(self.indent * self.getpos()[1] + value + ' {\n')
    self.pos = self.getpos()[1]
```

If you needed to test for certain attributes, your only option is to *first* scan for the `id` and `class` attributes; there may be more than one such key-value pair, and it appears you only want to match the first occurrences.

Luckily, a `dict` object would make this easy, but do *reverse* the key-value pairs so that only the *first* `id` or `class` key-value pair is used (in reverse order they'd override any extra class or id key-value pairs):

```
attrs_dict = dict(reversed(attrs))

if 'id' in attrs_dict:
    value = '#' + attrs_dict['id']
elif 'class' in attrs_dict:
    value = '.' + attrs_dict['class']
else:
    value = tag

self.the_file.writelines(self.indent * self.getpos()[1] + value + ' {\n')
self.pos = self.getpos()[1]
```

Now the code picks the first `id` attribute (if one is present), otherwise the first `class` attribute, otherwise the tag name is used.

Comment: Thanks. I want value to have the id if the html tag has an id. I want it to to have the class if the tag has no id but a class. I want it to have the tag name (img, h1 etc) if there is no id or class. It needs to have only one, like either id or class or tag but not all. Is this what this code does?

Comment: @user3164083: it didn't but I added an option now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a dictionary?

```
d = dict([('class', 'title'), ('id', 'donkey'), ('src', 'images/DonkeyKongLogo.png')])
```

Then,

```
In [4]: 'id' in d
Out[4]: True
```

Not sure what you exactly want here, but I guess you can do something like:

```
In [5]: if 'id' in d: print d['id']
donkey
```

or even,

```
In [6]: if 'id' in d: print d['src']
images/DonkeyKongLogo.png

In [7]: if d['id'] == 'donkey': print d['src']
images/DonkeyKongLogo.png
```

Didn't get exactly what you wanted in your code ...

EDIT:

The code which you have shown should be written as:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if attrs != []:
        d = dict(attrs)             

        # some examples of the dictionary use ...

        if 'id' in d: print d['id']
        if ('id' in d) and (d['id'] == 'donkey') : print d['url']
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with exactly what I want from my code. Your solution is good. I am however getting a syntax error at the "In". I have `def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if attrs != []:
            d = dict(attrs)
            In [5]:if 'id' in d:print d['id']`

Comment: `In[5]` is in the iPython interpreter prompt. You should say `if 'id' in d: print d['id']`

Answer (score 0):

Flatten all the sub tuples into a single list and search for the attribute and then its value:

```
import itertools

attrs = [('class', 'title'), ('id', 'donkey'), ('src', 'images/DonkeyKongLogo.png')]

dump = [y for y in itertools.chain(*attrs)] 
#dump = ['class', 'title', 'id', 'donkey' , 'src', 'images/DonkeyKongLogo.png']

if 'id' in dump: value = dump[dump.index('id') + 1]
elif 'class' in dump: value = dump[dump.index('class') + 1]
else: value = dump[1]

print value
```

This assumes that if there is no `id` or `class` attribute then the attribute will only have a single tuple containing `tag` and `value`

Answer (score 0):

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    id=None
    clas=None
    for attr,value in attrs:
        if attr=='id':
            id='#'+value
            break    # Only since highest priority
        elif attr=='class':
            clas = '.'+value
    value=id or clas or tag
    self.the_file.writelines(self.indent * self.getpos()[1] + value + ' {' +'\n')
    self.pos = self.getpos()[1]
```

This uses the shortcutting behaviour of [`or`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) combined with the trueness of non-empty strings and falseness of None. It doesn't account for multiple classes, but will simply pick the last one (add `and not clas` at the elif to get the first instead). A similar method would be to convert the list of attributes into a dictionary, but that also only saves the last of each attribute, and in this case we wanted to handle them in individual ways (prepend the period or hash sign).

Another variant is to use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to merely define a priority function:

```
def prio(cur, (attr,value)):
    if attr=='id':
        return '#'+value
    elif attr=='class' and cur[0] not in '#.':
        return '.'+value  # found a class, and had neither class nor id
    else:
        return cur
```

The selection then becomes fairly simple:

```
In [10]: reduce(prio,[('class', 'title'), ('id', 'donkey')],'img')
Out[10]: '#donkey'
In [11]: reduce(prio,[('unknown','irrelevant')],'img')
Out[11]: 'img'
In [12]: reduce(prio,[('class','foo')],'img')
Out[12]: '.foo'
In [13]: reduce(prio,[('class','foo'),('class','bar')],'img')
Out[13]: '.foo'
```